# What will be a way to refactor the following ruby code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
def self.method_A 
  a = xx
  b = xx
  c = xx
  d = xx

  complex_computing1(a, b, c, d)
end


def self.method_B
  a = xx
  b = xx
  c = xx
  d = xx

  complex_computing2(a, b, c, d)
end
```

I need to refactor the above code, so I create A method called `method_C`

```
def self.method_C
  return {
    a: xx,
    b: xx,
    c: xx,
    d: xx,
  }
end
```

So, in method_A

it will become

```
def self.method_A
  result = method_C
  complex_computing1(result[:a], result[:b], result[:c], result[:d])
end
```

But I don't think it is the best way, can anyone give me more suggestion?

Comment: You can create a constant in this class to DRY things up

Comment: Without full details about what `a,b,c,d` are, what the complex computings are, if `a,b,c,d` are the same in mA and mB? and if they are does complex_computing1 and 2 just take the same values but do different operations on them? and etc, it's really difficult to figure out what and how to refactor.

Comment: Thank your suggestion. Due to the original code is really verbose and unclear, I abstracted the actual code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I assume you've abstracted your actual code – which makes it difficult to suggest actual working refactorings since it's unclear what is constant and what is the result of additional calculations. For the sake of my suggestion, I'll assume that all values denoted by `xx` are the results of method calls and thus can't simply be turned into a constant like Shimu suggested.

In this case, then, the probably cleanest way to refactor would be this:

```
def self.method_A
  complex_computing1(*method_C.values_at(:a, :b, :c, :d))
end
```

If they keys don't carry real logic, you can leverage the fact that hashes are ordered in Ruby (at least since Ruby 1.9) and do this:

```
def self.method_A
  complex_computing1(*method_C.values)
end
```

Hope that answers your question.